jsonpath.net - identify string matches in descendants of dissimilar objects
Considering the following example JSON:
{
    "SH1": {
        "Locations": [
            {
                "Downstream Device": [
                    {
                        "value": "Conveyor - Accumulating:CN2.Tracking Data(1)"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Downstream Device": [
                    {
                        "value": "Conveyor - Accumulating:CN3.Tracking Data(1)"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "type": "Shuttle"
    },
    "CN1": {
        "Downstream Device": [
            {
                "value": "Shuttle:SH1.Tracking Data(1)"
            }
        ],
        "type": "Conveyor - Single Item"
    },
    "CN2": {
        "Downstream Device": [
            {
                "value": "Downstream Process:DP2.Tracking Data(1)"
            }
        ],
        "type": "Conveyor - Accumulating"
    },
    "RB1": {
        "Downstream Device": [
            {
                "value": "Downstream Process:DP1.Tracking Data(1)"
            }
        ],
        "type": "Depositor"
    }
}

Using jsonpath.net, I would like to create a single query that returns a non-empty result whenever

property "type" is "Shuttle" and any of the child "value" properties contains a search string, or
property "type" is "Conveyor - Single Item" or "Conveyor - Accumulating", and any of the child "value" properties contains a search string.

For example:

search strings "CN2", "CN3", "SH1" and "DP2" returns a non-empty result.
search string "DP1" returns []

I can do this for the individual types as such:

$[?@.type=="Shuttle"]["Locations"][?search(@["Downstream Device"][0].value, SEARCH_STRING)]
$[?@.type=="Conveyor - Single Item" || @.type=="Conveyor - Accumulating"]["Downstream Device"][?search(@.value, SEARCH_STRING)]

...but I am having trouble combining them into a single query.  How do I do that?  And if it's not possible, can it be made to work by removing the @.type condition and only having the @.value condition?

Testing with https://json-everything.net/json-path/, the following expression works with the above JSON example.  Split across multiple lines for clarity:
$[?    (@.type=="Conveyor - Single Item" || @.type=="Conveyor - Accumulating") 
       && 
       @["Downstream Device"][?search(@.value, SEARCH_STRING)] 

  ||   @.type=="Shuttle" 
       && 
       @["Locations"][*]["Downstream Device"][?search(@.value, SEARCH_STRING)]
]

